# Named parameters functions in Clojure

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

This code discussing named arguments in Clojure from "The Joy of Clojure":

```
(defn slope [& {:keys [p1 p2] :or {p1 [0 0] p2 [1 1]}}] 
   (float (/ (- (p2 1) (p1 1))
             (- (p2 0) (p1 0)))))

(slope :p1 [4 15] :p2 [3 21])
```

The function itself, I understand it -no problem with destructuring- but I don't understand the calling.
Are we passing four arguments to slope? how vectors are getting assigned to :p1 and :p2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing four arguments to slope, yes. The `[]` part of `slope` specifies the parameters, in which `&` means "slurp all additional parameters into this form", which then specifies that it is looking for arguments that form a map with keys `p1` and `p2` (and gives default values if either doesn't exist).

Comment: I got that but when calling: (slope :p1 [4 15] :p2 [3 21])  how p1 gets the value [4 15] and p2 [3 21] ?

Comment: `p1` got the value `[4 15]` because the arguments `:p1 [4 15] :p2 [3 21]` are treated as a map, and the parameter block in `slope` says to bind the variables `p1` and `p2` to their corresponding values in that map.